# AWS s3api 'get-object' costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to download this 60 milions tweets dataset (https://github.com/compsocial/CREDBANK-data) for my thesis work.
So I signed up for an AWS account and configured it with the correct parameters in my Mac terminal, then I signed in also into the S3 page, BUT when I try the following command:

`aws s3api get-object --request-payer requester --bucket credbank --key stream_tweets_byTimestamp.data stream_tweets_byTimestamp.data`

I get this error message:

*An error occurred (NotSignedUp) when calling the GetObject operation: Your account is not signed up for the S3 service. You must sign up before you can use S3.*

So, from what I understand, the problem is that my prepaid card wasn't accepted as a valid payment method and therefore my account isn't fully activated yet.

So, my question is, if I only need to run the `get-object` command above to download the data, could I be charged for some money if I use a real credit card, even if with my new account I'm in the 12-months free tier period?

Please let me know if you need further details to understand my question!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your card will not be charged a single penny unless one of these happens:
a) You use >5 GB of Standard Storage. This one is really important in your case so ensure the data size you will be downloading
b) You make >20,000 Get Requests
c) You make >2,000 Put Requests

I've signed up for AWS free tier and used their S3 and EC2 services for a year without bearing any cost.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 

Do you know if there is a way to view the size of my needed data before downloading it?

Comment: Simply send a HEAD request instead of GET request. It would give you the required header and leave out the actual body. You can then parse out the Content-Length header value from the HTTP response headers.

Comment: I run ` aws s3api head-object  --bucket credbank --key stream_tweets_byTimestamp.data` but I get the message "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden". Could be related to permission problems of the person who own the bucket or is it my fault?

Comment: It could be happening for the reason you mentioned or some other reasons. If the bucket is truly public, then it might be happening because of the region. Make sure you give an explicit region parameter where this bucket is and/or access it from the ec2 box, running in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

If the file you want to download is smaller than 15GB, then the download will cost you nothing, even if you use a real credit card.

You'll only use 1 GET request (you have 20,000 free) and a portion of the 15 GB of free download transfer per month.

[Source:](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

> As part of the AWS Free Usage Tier, you can get started with Amazon S3
>   for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5 GB of Amazon S3
>   storage in the Standard Storage class, 20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put
>   Requests, and 15 GB of data transfer out each month for one year.